# When initializing a promise with a closure/resolver, can we throw directly?

Tags: swift, promisekit

PromiseKit has this initializer for `Promise`:

```
/// Initialize a new promise that can be resolved with the provided `Resolver`.
public init(resolver body: (PromiseKit.Resolver<T>) throws -> Void)
```

Sometimes I need my function to return a `Promise` but the return value of that function depends on other throwing functions. Is it valid to call `try` directly without a `do/catch` block since the `resolver` closure throws? Or must I wrap each throwing function in `do` and in the `catch` call `seal.reject(error)`?

I would prefer to directly use `try` because it is much cleaner to return the end result without the `do/catch`.

This issue seems relevant, but I'd like some confirmation on these approaches since it isn't called out in the docs: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/799.

Is this valid?

```
  private func getCNContacts() -> Promise<[CNContact]> {
    return Promise { seal in
      let fullNameKeyDescriptor = CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)
      guard let keysToFetch = [fullNameKeyDescriptor, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as? [CNKeyDescriptor] else {
        throw CKPersistenceError.failedToFetch("Could not cast as [CNKeyDescriptor]")
      }

      var results: [CNContact] = []
      let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
      try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, _ in
        results.append(contact)
      }

      seal.fulfill(results)
    }
  }
```

Or must I use `do/catch` like this:

```
private func getCNContacts() -> Promise<[CNContact]> {
    return Promise { seal in
      let fullNameKeyDescriptor = CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)
      guard let keysToFetch = [fullNameKeyDescriptor, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as? [CNKeyDescriptor] else {
        seal.reject(CKPersistenceError.failedToFetch("Could not cast as [CNKeyDescriptor]"))
        return
      }

      do {
        var results: [CNContact] = []
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, _ in
          results.append(contact)
        }
        seal.fulfill(results)
      } catch {
        seal.reject(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

There's also this possibility, but I think it might have threading implications:

```
  private func getCNContacts() -> Promise<[CNContact]> {
    let fullNameKeyDescriptor = CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)
    guard let keysToFetch = [fullNameKeyDescriptor, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as? [CNKeyDescriptor] else {
      let error = CKPersistenceError.failedToFetch("Could not cast as [CNKeyDescriptor]")
      return Promise(error: error)
    }

    do {
      var results: [CNContact] = []
      let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
      try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, _ in
        results.append(contact)
      }
      return Promise.value(results)
    } catch {
      return Promise(error: error)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to have have throwing function inside Promise and not handle the error within the promise resolution block.

But, if you want to handle the error you could use `catch(on: flags:, policy: , _ )`,

Here is small experiment that I did based on your question.

```
    simplePromise =  Promise { resolver in
        let string = try self.getSomeString()
        resolver.resolve(Result.fulfilled(string))
    }

    simplePromise.done { results in
        print(results)
    }.catch { error in
        print("Error occurred: \(error)")
    }
```

Now, if my method `getSomeString()` throws, the code inside `catch` block is called but if it is resolved successfully, then code inside `done` is called.

You could try out by creating the method `getSomeString` and throwing from there like so,

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case sampleError
}

func getSomeString() throws -> String {
    throw MyError.sampleError
}
```

And, also try out by not throwing.

So, it seems like usual way to handle the error of throwing function is implementing `catch` callback.

You could also not implement catch yourself and your code would not crash. In the end the throwing functions are treated as `sealed.reject`

By the way, if you wish you can look at the code. You dont have to handle the error with `do { } catch` but PromiseKit does it internally, look [here](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Sources/Promise.swift#L60) for your reference.